# Show that $\{X_n\}$ forms a martingale

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-variables, expected-value, martingales

Let $\{\xi_i\}^\infty_{i=0}$ be a sequence of real valued jointly distributed random variables that satisfy $E[\xi_i|\xi_0,\xi_1,...,\xi_{i-1}]=0,\;i=1,2,...$ Define
$$X_0=\xi_0,\quad X_{n+1}=\sum^n_{i=0}\xi_{i+1}f_i(\xi_0,\xi_1,...,\xi_i)$$
where $f_i$ are a prescribed sequence of functions of $i+1$ real variables. Show that $\{X_n\}$ form a martingale.

We want to show that $E[X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]=X_n$.
\begin{align}
E[X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]&=E[\sum^n_{i=0}\xi_{i+1}f_i(\xi_0,\xi_1,...,\xi_i)|\mathcal{F}_n]\\
&=\sum^n_{i=0}E[\xi_{i+1}f_i(\xi_0,\xi_1,...,\xi_i)|\mathcal{F}_n]\\
&=\sum^n_{i=0}f_i(\xi_0,\xi_1,...,\xi_i)E[\xi_{i+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]
\end{align}

The part that I am stuck on is what to do with the sequence $f_i$. I can see that it has something to do with $E[\xi_i|\xi_0,\xi_1,...,\xi_{i-1}]=0$, but how do I use this to conclude that it equals $X_n$. Also, do we have to figure out what $X_n$ is from $X_{n+1}$ since it is not given?

Comment: Note that $f_i(\xi_0,\xi_1,...,\xi_i)$ is $\mathcal F_n$ measurable for all $n \ge i$.

Comment: Does that mean that it simplifies to $\sum^n_{i=0}E[\xi_{i+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]$? Can you explain how you knew it was $\mathcal{F}_n$ measurable? Thank you so much

Comment: It's $\mathcal F_n$ measurable because it only depends on $\xi_i$ for $i \le n$, i.e. knowing all information up to time $n$ is enough to evaluate it.  It simplifies to $\sum f_i(\xi_0,\xi_1,...,\xi_i)E[\xi_{i+1}|\mathcal F_n]$ because being $\mathcal F_n$ measurable just means it can move outside of the conditional expectation, not disappear entirely :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote by $\mathcal F_n$ the natural filtration of $X_n$.

Suppose that $\mathcal G_n = \sigma(\xi_0, \xi_1, \ldots, \xi_n)$. In this case  $f_n(\xi_0,\xi_1,...,\xi_n)$ are $\mathcal{G}_n$ - measurable and $$E[\xi_{n+1}f_n(\xi_0,\xi_1,...,\xi_1)|\mathcal{G}_n] = f_n(\xi_0,\xi_1,...,\xi_n) E[\xi_{n+1}|\mathcal{G}_n] = 0.$$
Thus $E[X_{n+1} - X_n|\mathcal{G}_n] = 0$ or equivalently   $E[X_{n+1}|\mathcal{G}_n] = X_n$.

Hence $X_n$ is a  martingale with respect to $\mathcal{G}_n$.

Finally we use the next fact, which may be easily checked: if $X_n$ is a  martingale with respect to $\mathcal{G}_n$ then $X_n$ is a martingale with respect to it's natural filtration $\mathcal F_n$.